# Reading specific columns in a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a text file with data in the following format

```
15.26   14.84   0.871   5.763   3.312   2.221   5.22    1
14.88   14.57   0.8811  5.554   3.333   1.018   4.956   1
......
```

I am able to read the file using the following synchronous method

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('data.txt').toString().split("\n");

for(var i in data){
  console.log(data[i]);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to only store the values from columns 3,4 and 5 from the file

So my final output needs to look like

```
[[0.871, 5.763, 3.312], [...], [...], ......]
```

How can I achieve this, is there an existing library or module that i can use?

Comment: Did you think about `string.split('\t')` and `array.slice(2,5)` ?

Comment: yep that did it thanks @KonstantinA.Magg

Comment: Great. When I make an answer, can you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just continue with `string` and `array` operations:

- `string.split('\t')` (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split))
- `array.slice(2,5)` (see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))